# Can someone help me with the update function in Matlab to move values to MySQL?

Tags: matlab

I'm dealing with a problem with the update function in Matlab.

```
conn=database('MySQL','user','password');)
selectquery_select = 'SELECT * FROM inputs WHERE i_read = 0';
data_select = select(conn,selectquery_select);
for j=1:size(data_select)
       id_data = data_select(j,1);
       id_data = string(id_data.(1));
       time_data = data_select(j,4);
       time_data = string(time_data.(1));
       time_dataform = datetime(time_data,'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'); 
       y0=data_select(j,2);
       y0 = str2num(string(y0.(1))); 
       r0=data_select(j,3);
       r0 = str2num(string(r0.(1)));
       
       if id_data == "115"
           run("C:\Users\...\uu.m")
           update(conn,'inputs','i_read',1,'WHERE (ID_code = "115") AND WHERE (i_Time = time_data)');
       end 
end
```

Basically, I'm taking some value from the database when i_read is equal to 0 (i_read is a boolean variable in the database that should give 1 if the value is already processed and 0 if not). After a value is read, we want to change the i_read in the database from 0 to 1. We decide to use the update function, but this gave us the following error:

```
Error using database.odbc.connection/update
Too many input arguments.

Error in Patient_Identification (line 57)
           update(conn,'inputs','i_read',1,'WHERE (ID_code = "112") AND WHERE (i_Time = ', time_data,')');
```

Someone is able to help us with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: You're passing your where clause as multiple arguments. Make it a single string and then pass it. Try making a variable called `whereclause` to help you isolate that problem.

Comment: We've tried to create a whereclause variable like whereclause=['WHERE (ID_code = "112") AND WHERE (i_Time = ', time_data,')']. But the code gives us this error: 

Error using database.odbc.connection/update (line 301)
ODBC Driver Error: [Microsoft][Driver Manager ODBC] Errore nella sequenza della funzione.
Error in Patient_Identification (line 59)
           update(conn,'inputs','i_read',1,whereclause);

Comment: maybe this is a stupid question, but, have you installed the ODBC driver ?

Comment: also noticed that you're closing your string after `i_Time = `, making your string invalid as pointed out by L.Scott

Comment: I've solved the problem, thank you